# Kion signifas la vorto 'montsuvereno'?

Tags: translation

Mi trovis ĝin en la libro 'adiaŭ, Kuzko'. La vorto 'suvereno' signifas la moneron de Unuiĝinta Reĝlando, sed mi ne komprenas kion signifas MONTsuvereno.

Comment: Estus bone aldoni iom da kunteksto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alia signifo de *suvereno* estas la jena:

> Tiu, kiu en regno havas la plej superan povon

—[PIV](http://vortaro.net/#suvereno)

Mi ne konas la libron, do mankas al mi la kunteksto, sed ŝajnas al mi, ke *montsuvereno* simple estas suvereno de iu specifa monto.